# R - How to generate a List of dataframes with character() elements

Tags: r, list, text, dataframe

How can you make a list of text-section-dataframes **editstart (for a given text) editend**, where every sentence of the section has a specific ID? (Unlike the simple example below, number of sentences is not always the same.)

```
sent <- character()
id <- character()
section <- data.frame(SentIDs=character(), Sentences=character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
textList <- list(section)

sections <- 3
sentences <- 5

for(i in 1:sections){
   for (j in 1:sentences){
      textList[[i]][j,1] <- paste(i, j, sep=",")      # ID of one sentence is put into the section dataframe inside the textList
      textList[[i]][j,2] <- paste("sent", j, sep=" ") # sentence is put into the section dataframe inside the textList
   }
}
textList
```

Returned ERROR & wrong output

```
Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

> textList
[[1]]
  SentIDs Sentences
1     1,1    sent 1
2     1,2    sent 2
3     1,3    sent 3
4     1,4    sent 4
5     1,5    sent 5
```

Required OUTPUT

```
> textList    
[[1]]
  SentIDs Sentences
1     1,1    sent 1
2     1,2    sent 2
3     1,3    sent 3
4     1,4    sent 4
5     1,5    sent 5

[[2]]
  SentIDs Sentences
1     2,1    sent 1
2     2,2    sent 2
3     2,3    sent 3
4     2,4    sent 4
5     2,5    sent 5

[[3]]
  SentIDs Sentences
1     3,1    sent 1
2     3,2    sent 2
3     3,3    sent 3
4     3,4    sent 4
5     3,5    sent 5
```

Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `for` loops, you will get more concise and efficient code with something from the `apply` family of functions:

```
sections <- 3
sentences <- 5
textList <- lapply(1:sections, function(x) {
  data.frame(SentIDs=paste0(x, ",", 1:sentences),
             Sentences=paste("sent", 1:sentences))
})
textList

# [[1]]
#   SentIDs Sentences
# 1     1,1    sent 1
# 2     1,2    sent 2
# 3     1,3    sent 3
# 4     1,4    sent 4
# 5     1,5    sent 5
# 
# [[2]]
#   SentIDs Sentences
# 1     2,1    sent 1
# 2     2,2    sent 2
# 3     2,3    sent 3
# 4     2,4    sent 4
# 5     2,5    sent 5
# 
# [[3]]
#   SentIDs Sentences
# 1     3,1    sent 1
# 2     3,2    sent 2
# 3     3,3    sent 3
# 4     3,4    sent 4
# 5     3,5    sent 5
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a `replicate` job by excellence. No need to use a for loop. Using option `simplify=FALSE` allow to have a list as an output.

```
set.seed(1)
replicate(3,{
        n=sample(1:4,1)   ## random number of rows
        ID = seq_len(n)
        data.frame(ID=ID,sent=paste("sent", ID))},
          simplify=FALSE)

[[1]]
  ID   sent
1  1 sent 1
2  2 sent 2

[[2]]
  ID   sent
1  1 sent 1
2  2 sent 2

[[3]]
  ID   sent
1  1 sent 1
2  2 sent 2
3  3 sent 3
```

**EDIT** after OP clarification:

You should use `lapply` here since you have a list. Use also `seq_along` and `seq_len` functions to create index along or giving vector length.

```
 lapply(seq_along(ll),function(i)
   data.frame(sent=ll[[i]],
              Id=paste(i,seq_along(ll[[i]]),sep=",")))
```

Comment: A1! Thank you much! my issue was how to create a list - my fault. In my original context i already have the sentences, and the position is actually known, but I could not generate the proper list object.

Comment: @alex do you have a list of sentences that you want to split  randomly in many lists?

Comment: in the original code i have a list (elements representing sections) of vectors (elements representing sentences) without IDs. the challenge is to create a similar list, but with added IDs for every sentence. My question may was a bit wonky. I'm relatively new in this field. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define each `section` in the outer portion of the loop:

```
sent <- character()
id <- character()
textList <- list()


sections <- 3
sentences <- 5

for(i in 1:sections){
   textList[[i]] <- data.frame(SentIDs=character(), Sentences=character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

   for (j in 1:sentences){
      textList[[i]][j,1] <- paste(i, j, sep=",")      # ID of one sentence is put into the section dataframe inside the textList
      textList[[i]][j,2] <- paste("sent", j, sep=" ") # sentence is put into the section dataframe inside the textList
   }
}
textList
```